# wordpress site page infected with malicuious code

Tags: wordpress, security

I have an issue with my WordPress site.

My website is generating adult pages which is not present on our website/database or server. It is showing in google search result like this for example siteurl.com/en/aarp-dating (around 500 pages google crawled) we have checked all our database and found around 30 new tables are automatically created and while we delete it after sometime it restore automatically.

How can I find the malicious code on my server/pages or what kind of problem is this?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Download the full installation, then compare the files' checksums with a clean backup or a fresh installation of the same WP + Plugins + Theme versions.

Most important: find out how they infected your site and close that hole or you will be back at square one in a short time after you've uploaded a clean backup. Check the Access Logs, filter out known IP addresses of you and your users, and look at the rest, especially POST requests. Also make sure to check the FTP-logs and (if you have ssh access to your host) auth logs to make sure that your/your coworkers' machines/passwords haven't been compromised.

Also make sure you don't miss any extra individual files or plugins that shouldn't be there.

You cannot trust what you see in the backend at this point, so check the database directly for new users you don't know and users with privileges they shouldn't have. Comparing with a recent backup can help.

Since it's not clear how long your site has been infected, I wouldn't trust recent backups (or any, really) either. Set up a fresh install after you found and fixed the entry point, then manually (or with a script, but be careful not to transfer back doors) transfer content to the clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wordfence Security Plugin & scan for infected core files of wordpress.
Use Sucuri plugin.

Also, desactivate ALL of your plugin and install a basic theme of wordpress before.